# Cannot load a library on the client in a Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

https://github.com/mohrtw/NuxtLoadLibraryOnClient/tree/master

## NuxtLoadLibraryOnClient

### Problem:

Our imported library is not loading on the client.

### How the app works:

- pages/index.vue import SO from "../static/someObjects.js";
- asyncData creates an SO.AnObject
- components/util/objectLoader receives the SO.AnObject as prop 'obj'
- objectLoader's objectProcessor checks what instanceOf 'obj' is, then returns a property of that object
- objectLoader displays the data received from index.vue

### What we've tried:

- placing   the library in static, assets, and plugins
- loading   the library in the store
- loading   data with fetch instead of asyncData

### How it should work:

- objectLoader's objectProcessor checks whether the data passed to it is an instanceOf AnObject or AnotherObject,
  then returns either the name or the title.
- The browser should then   display "Object data: Mohr" instead of "Object data: didn't work"

Placing a debugger in `objectProcessor` shows that the correct data loads   on the server,
but the imported SO and OO objects are undefined, so it fails the instanceOf checks and returns "didn't work"

**components/util/objectLoader.vue**:

```

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>from objectLoader</h1>
    <h2>Object data: {{objectProcessor(obj)}}</h2>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import SO from '../../static/someObjects';
import OO from '../../static/otherObjects';
//debugger;
export default {
    props:  ['obj'],

    methods: {
        objectProcessor: function (obj) {
            /* returns a name or title depending
            on the type of object
            */
            var result = '';
            debugger; // eslint-disable-line

            if (obj instanceof SO.AnObject) {
                result = obj.name; 
                console.log(result);
            } else if (obj instanceof OO.AnotherObject) {
                result = obj.title;
            } else {
                result = 'didn\'t work';
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```